# Aborted HTTP requests in ASP.NET MVC app when using squid proxy

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, httprequest, squid

The project I'm working on is an ASP.NET MVC5 / SQL Server application hosted on an IIS7 web server. The application is running on port 80.

My company is using squid as a web proxy. When the web application is used via the proxy, HTTP requests are aborted after 20 seconds.

When squid is turned off the application works fine without any timeout.

Nothing in the squid configuration files seem to indicate that a 20 second time out has been set.

To confuse things even further, when accessing (via squid) sites such as

https://httpbin.org/drip?duration=1&numbytes=1&code=1&delay=25

(test site where a 25 seconds delay is introduced before the start of the request) things seem to work OK - i.e. squid does not abort the request.

We are a bit stuck now about what to investigate. Any ideas?